# Mapping json string to interace with anonymous class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, mapping

I have an interface, which I want to use for serialize/deserialize. I want to omit some of the fields. Code below is not working so far.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface MyWrapper {
    //no annotation to not serialize
    String getMyField();

    //annotation to deserialize
    @JsonProperty("my_field")
    void setMyField();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either specify `@JsonIgnore` annotation on the method, or `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"myfield"})` annotation on the class.

[see examples here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)

EDIT:
which version of Jackson are you using? becuase in the one I am using (2.5) the use of `@JsonIgnore` together with `@JsonProperty` works perfectly.
also, notice that the setter needs to receive an argument to actually be used by Jackson

interface with fixed setter:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public interface MyWrapper {
    @JsonIgnore
    String getMyField();

    // annotation to deserialize
    @JsonProperty("my_field")
    void setMyField(String f);
}
```

implementation (nothing exciting here)

```
public class Foo implements MyWrapper {
    private String myField;

    public Foo() {}
    public Foo(String f) {
        setMyField(f);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMyField() {
        return myField;
    }

    @Override
    public void setMyField(String f) {
        myField = f;
    }
}
```

testing :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // serialization - ignore field
    try {
        MyWrapper w = new Foo("value");
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(w);
        System.out.println("serialized MyWrapper: " + json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // de-serialization - read field
    String json = "{\"my_field\":\"value\"}";
    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
        MyWrapper w = (MyWrapper)mapper.readValue(is, Foo.class);
        System.out.println("deserialized MyWrapper: input: " + json + " ; w.getMyField(): " + w.getMyField());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
serialized MyWrapper: {}
deserialized MyWrapper: input: {"my_field":"value"} ; w.getMyField(): value
```

Comment: It ignores it totally then, I need to include it during deserialization and ignore on serialization